# How can I use bcrypted password in a query?

Tags: php, mysql

Before I start, I will state that at the moment I'm stuck with the old mysql API.

I use this function for password creation.

```
$password = $_POST[password];
$passwordhashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

However, now I need to run a query like this one:

```
$query_f = mysql_query("SELECT fiscal FROM list WHERE password='$password'");
```

but obviously I can't use `$password` because in the database it's encrypted with a random salt. So how do I do it?

This is not what I'm actually gonna do. For the reasons I don't wanna bother you with, I would like to know if it's possible and how.

Comment: Look at [password_verify](http://php.net/password_verify) examples. Usually, you would query you DB using the username (why you're querying for the password I have no idea), then use password_verify to compare the provided password (plain) with the hashed one returned from the DB.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: To answer your question: No, it's not possible. Everytime you use `password_hash` PHP automatically generates a secure salt and makes everytime you hash the password generate a different hash (even if it's the same). You need to use an unique identifier (like username or email) and then use `password_verify` to look if the provided (plain) password matches with the saved hash representation.

Comment: @SaulTigh Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice.

Comment: @SaulTigh Please try and stay constructive here. Yelling at people is not helping. Your code is dangerously insecure and people are trying to get you on the right track. The consequences of making a mistake like this can be [catastrophic to your company and career](http://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/). Do not hand wave this away.

Comment: In your code here you take a `$_POST` value and put it directly in the query. That's all you need for a long list of [very bad things](http://sqlmap.org/) to happen to your server. If you make a habit of doing this you're going to get in trouble eventually. Additionally, regardless of your constraints, `mysql_query` has a number of security flaws that will never be fixed. This is why it was removed from PHP 7. The reason I'm so adamant about this sort of thing is because one day I might put personal information into a site you've written, and then that data might get leaked. Be vigilant.

Comment: The real answer was given by Chris. This is a non-reversible function by design and you cannot look up arbitrary passwords without doing a computationally expensive `password_verify` on each row in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. Look up the user by some identifier (like a username or email address) and then check if the password field matches with [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). You specifically can't lookup a user by salted password hash, that would defeat the point of salting.

Comment: Also the hash changes with every hashing, even with the password is the same, due to a random cryptographically generated salt.